# almost realtime push down relation vs realtime pushdown relation?

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automata, transducers

Almost realtime pushdown relation pop a symbol for each empty step.
Realtime pushdown relation does not perform any empty step.

What do they mean by empty step?